# What's the best way to create a dev version of a SQL Server database?

Tags: sql-server, database-replication

I just inherited a project from someone else, and I was wondering whether there's an easy way to identify all of the relationship dependencies in a DB so that you can easily delete a bulk of the data from production in order to create a developer copy but keep the relationships for the remaining accounts intact.

Comment: [Red-Gate SQL Compare](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-compare/). You can compare the schema of your production database to an empty one, then create the schema without any of the data. Also [read this](http://madelinebertrand.com/2012/04/20/re-blog-the-cost-of-reinventing-the-wheel/) in case you're tempted to write your own code to "save money."

Comment: (Also, define "best"...

Comment: It sounded like the schema wasn't the issue, he wanted to have some "dev" data created or preserved from the prod data.

Comment: Do you need to work with only a subset of the production data, or can you just copy the complete database? Unless it's huge, it's usually easier to just backup the production database and restore it on a dev server. Not only is it faster and easier, but you don't have to deal with the (difficult) task of removing a consistent subset of the data. You could accidentally remove data that has specific processing logic, so you might find unit tests passing and then failing when you go back to production, or other odd issues.

Comment: The problem is the client is not knowledgeable about such things, and as such has sent me a backup of the production database. So, yes, I only want to work with a subset of the production data, such as those accounts which are already being used for test purposes. The unzipped backup file is 1.7 GB and crashed my machine so I had to rebuild it from scratch (which is why it's been a week since I've responded on this thread).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will give you the "template SQL" in the correct order.

But you'll have to fill in some missing where clause stuff (not trivial).

```
;
with    cteTableHierarchy 
          as ( /* Select all table without (selfreferencing) FK */
               select distinct
                        1 as LevelID
                      , OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(Parent.object_id) as TableOwner
                      , Parent.name as TableName
                      , Parent.object_id as TbObjID

               from     sys.objects Parent
               left join sys.foreign_key_columns RefKey
                        On RefKey.parent_object_id = Parent.object_id
                           and RefKey.parent_object_id <> RefKey.referenced_object_id
                           and RefKey.constraint_column_id = 1
               where    RefKey.parent_object_id is null
                        and Parent.type = 'U'
                        and Parent.name <> 'dtproperties'
               UNION ALL
               /* add tables that reference the anchor rows */
               SELECT   H.LevelID + 1
                      , OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(Parent.object_id) as TableOwner
                      , OBJECT_NAME(Parent.object_id) as TableName
                      , Parent.object_id as TbObjID
               from     sys.objects Parent
               inner join sys.foreign_key_columns RefKey
                        On RefKey.parent_object_id = Parent.object_id
                           and RefKey.parent_object_id <> RefKey.referenced_object_id
                           and RefKey.constraint_column_id = 1
               inner join cteTableHierarchy H
                        on H.TbObjID = RefKey.referenced_object_id 
               where    Parent.type = 'U'
                        and Parent.name <> 'dtproperties'
             )
    select distinct *    , TemplateSQL = 'Delete from [' + TableOwner + '].[' + TableName + '] Where .... '
    from    cteTableHierarchy
    order by LevelID desc -- descending order = order of row deletes
          , TableOwner
          , TableName ;
```

EDIT ........................

Comment out the "Select *" and uncomment the "Delete deleteAlias" to actually perform the deletes.  The good thing about this little syntax sugar (Select * vs "Delete deleteAlias" is you can quickly see the EXACT data (via the select *) that you are going to actually delete "Delete deleteAlias".

The below populates a small @Holder variable table.
Then will reverse walk the 3 tables.......to delete the data.

Note, the last table (from dbo.[Customers] deleteAlias) has some redundant/unnecessary code, but I'm trying to show the concept over "conciseness".

```
Use Northwind
Go




/* Example to Delete all Order-Details, Orders, Customers based on a known list of CustomerID's */

declare @CustomerIDHolder table ( CustomerID char(5) )
INSERT INTO @CustomerIDHolder ( CustomerID )
Select 'ALFKI' union all select '33333'


--Delete deleteAlias 
  Select * 
from dbo.[Order Details] deleteAlias
where exists 
    ( select null from dbo.[Orders] innerOrds join dbo.Customers innerCusts on innerOrds.CustomerID = innerCusts.CustomerID 
        where
        /* exists inner to outer relationshiop */
        innerOrds.OrderId = deleteAlias.OrderId
        and
        /* filter */
        exists ( Select null from @CustomerIDHolder innerInnerHolder where innerInnerHolder.CustomerID = innerCusts.CustomerID )
  )


--Delete deleteAlias 
  Select * 
from dbo.[Orders] deleteAlias
where exists 
    ( select null from dbo.Customers innerCusts
        where
        /* exists inner to outer relationshiop */
        innerCusts.CustomerID = deleteAlias.CustomerID
        and
        /* filter */
        exists ( Select null from @CustomerIDHolder innerInnerHolder where innerInnerHolder.CustomerID = innerCusts.CustomerID )
  )


--Delete deleteAlias 
  Select * 
from dbo.[Customers] deleteAlias
where exists 
    ( select null from dbo.Customers innerCusts
        where
        /* exists inner to outer relationshiop */
        innerCusts.CustomerID = deleteAlias.CustomerID
        and
        /* filter */
        exists ( Select null from @CustomerIDHolder innerInnerHolder where innerInnerHolder.CustomerID = innerCusts.CustomerID )
  )
```

And here is a "Mark things I want to keep, but delete the rest" example........

```
/* Example to Delete all Order-Details, Orders, Customers based on a known list of CustomerID's */

declare @CustomerIDHolder table ( CustomerID char(5) )
INSERT INTO @CustomerIDHolder ( CustomerID )
Select CustomerID from dbo.Customers

/* Keep all the data except for 2 Customers.  Aka, The Customers who do NOT exist in the holder table will be deleted.... */
Delete deleteAliasHolder From @CustomerIDHolder deleteAliasHolder where exists ( Select CustID from (Select 'ALFKI' as CustID union all select '33333' as CustID ) as derived1 where derived1.CustID = deleteAliasHolder.CustomerID )

Select CustomerID as DataToKeepCustomerID from @CustomerIDHolder 

--Delete deleteAlias 
  Select * 
from dbo.[Order Details] deleteAlias
where exists 
    ( select null from dbo.[Orders] innerOrds join dbo.Customers innerCusts on innerOrds.CustomerID = innerCusts.CustomerID 
        where
        /* exists inner to outer relationshiop */
        innerOrds.OrderId = deleteAlias.OrderId
        and
        /* filter */
        not exists ( Select null from @CustomerIDHolder innerInnerHolder where innerInnerHolder.CustomerID = innerCusts.CustomerID )
  )


--Delete deleteAlias 
  Select * 
from dbo.[Orders] deleteAlias
where exists 
    ( select null from dbo.Customers innerCusts
        where
        /* exists inner to outer relationshiop */
        innerCusts.CustomerID = deleteAlias.CustomerID
        and
        /* filter */
        not exists ( Select null from @CustomerIDHolder innerInnerHolder where innerInnerHolder.CustomerID = innerCusts.CustomerID )
  )


--Delete deleteAlias 
  Select * 
from dbo.[Customers] deleteAlias
where exists 
    ( select null from dbo.Customers innerCusts
        where
        /* exists inner to outer relationshiop */
        innerCusts.CustomerID = deleteAlias.CustomerID
        and
        /* filter */
        not exists ( Select null from @CustomerIDHolder innerInnerHolder where innerInnerHolder.CustomerID = innerCusts.CustomerID )
  )
```

Comment: Thank you @granadaCoder. Which `WHERE` clause is the one I need to update?

Comment: Right...that'll have to be filled in.  Let me come up with a Northwind example on how to "reverse climb the tree with selective deletes"